# I'm having issues with a computer headset

Tags: audio, headphones, headset

I just got a new pair of wireless headphones for Christmas. It's the HUHD HW-K5U Wireless 2.4GHz Gaming 7.1 Headset. It came with a transmitter USB stick that I plug into my computer so it doesn't actually pair with Bluetooth. I started up a game this morning and noticed that the sound quality is significantly worse than my previous headset which was not wireless. I know that wired headset naturally have better sound quality than wireless but is there any way to fix this problem or make the quality better?

I did some research on my own and found many solutions to a bluetooth related error where you go into the properties of the device and disable something called "Handsfree Telephony" but this is only available for bluetooth devices. If anyone has a solution or any ideas please let me know and if you need any more information I'd be delighted to give you what you need. Thanks!

P.S. I just want to stress that this is **NOT** a Bluetooth speaker.  The way I paired this with my computer was by inserting a USB dongle into the USB port and it basically paired it from there without me doing anything else (which seemed weird)

Comment: Wired headphones don't "naturally" have better audio.

Comment: Support at http://www.huhd.hk/index.php/Inquiry/index/g/e.html and https://www.amazon.com/HUHD-Wireless-Surround-Headphones-Controller/dp/B07TDWTJ7Z

Answer (score 0):

Your question, "the sound quality is significantly worse," is not descriptive enough to help with those issues that *could* be remedied. Here are some things to try [for *specific* issues](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice/voice-quality/30141-symptoms.html):

- You can compensate somewhat for *distortion* or a "tinny" sound, due to uneven sound reproduction volume across the audio range, with a graphic equalizer and trial-and-error adjustment. Your sound card driver may already have installed a graphic equalizer, or you can download others, e.g. [these for Windows OS](https://www.itechtics.com/audio-equalizer-enhancer/). BTW, you also neglected to state the OS.
- Background noise could be due to radio frequency interference (RFI), e.g. from a nearby cell phone, power supply harmonics, router, etc. Try moving the USB dongle to another location (an extension cable might help), and keeping other devices farther away.
- Missing segment or garbled sound sound could be due to a slow system. Use a USB 3.0 port... but other than that, your PC may not be able to keep up with the demands of both high frame-rate games and USB sound drivers.

Comment: Sorry for being unspecific.  I am running Windows 10, on a desktop computer used for gaming.  I also would describe the sound as a grainy type sound,  or a tinny sound like you said.  If I were to use one of these graphic equalizers like Equalizer APO, how would I do that, or rather how would that help me?  Thanks!

Comment: "Trial and error": Adjust the controls while listening. BTW, *edit* the question to add needed information, and, again, try to be specific. What do you mean by "grainy"? "Tinny" implies as if heard from a tin-can phone, i.e. woith resonances and limited range.

Comment: @ChetM You may want to edit your original question to include details like that. Also, if it is a tinny sound, read the manual of your headphones as some wireless headphones will have built in equalizer settings.